# Accessing an associative array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, associative-array

I have an associative array here -

```
var dataset = {
    "person" : [    
        {"userLabels": ["Name","Role"]},
        {"tagNames": ["lName","role"]},
        {"tableClass": "width530"},
        {"colWidths": ["50%","50%"]}
    ]
}
```

I tried accessing the 'userLabels' object using jQuery using various methods but I failed. I think I am doing something wrong with basics. I want the userLabels object to be accessed using jQuery and the result should be an array, so I can perform the jQuery.inArray() operation.

Comment: What do you mean by "using jQuery"? jQuery is just a Javascript library, it doesn't do anything special with objects (many of its methods accept objects, but that's just normal JS data use).

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, here's how you can access dataset using the method you have.

```
var dataset = 
{
  "person" : [  
          {"userLabels": ["Name","Role"]},
          {"tagNames": ["lName","role"]},
          {"tableClass": "width530"},
          {"colWidths": ["50%","50%"]}
         ]
};



 alert(dataset['person'][0]['userLabels']);    //style 1

 alert(dataset.person[0]['userLabels']);    //style 2

 alert(dataset.person[0].userLabels);    //style 3

 //Also you can use variables in place of specifying the names as well i.e.

 var propName ='userLabels';
 alert(dataset.person[0][propName]);

 //What follows is how to search if a value is in the array 'userLabels'
 $.inArray('Name', dataset.person[0].userLabels);
```

I'd like to ask why you're doing this in a such an 'interesting way'. Why don't you just make them all objects?

That's what I would do if I were you because if you think about it, a person IS an object and it should be noted that **arrays are basically objects** in Javascript with a 'length' property, though I won't elaborate on it here (feel free to do some research though). I'm guessing it's because you don't know how to iterate over object properties. Of course if it makes more sense to you, go for it.

Note one of the differences between an array and an object is that object properties need to be defined; you'll notice that I gave 'Name' and 'Role' values of 'undefined' below.

In any case, here is what I would do:

```
var dataset = 
{
  "person" : {
          "userLabels": {"Name" : undefined,"Role": undefined},
          "tagNames": {"lName" : undefined,"role" : undefined},
          "tableClass": "width530",
          "colWidths": ["50%","50%"]
        }
};

for (var i in dataset) { //iterate over all the objects in dataset
   console.log(dataset[i]);   //I prefer to use console.log() to write but it's only in firefox
   alert(dataset[i]);    // works in IE.
}

 //By using an object all you need to do is:

 dataset.person.userLabels.hasOwnProperty('Role'); //returns true or false
```

Anyways, hope this helps.

Comment: Missing a closing parenthesis on your alert, but otherwise, looks good.

Answer (score 2):

```
var basic = dataset.person[0].userLabels;
//          |        |     |
//          |        |     --- first element = target object
//          |        --- person property
//           ---- main-object
```

Comment: Yes, this does give me the userLabels array. But when I use alert(basic[0]) to get 'Name', it does not work!

Comment: The index keeps increasing for subsequent properties - 

var userLabels = dataset['person'][0]['userLabels'];
    var tagNames = dataset['person'][1]['tagNames'];
    var tableClass = dataset['person'][2]['tableClass'];
    var colWidths = dataset['person'][3]['colWidths'];

This works well throughout.

Answer (score 0):

```
var userLabels = dataset.person[0].userLabels;
if ($.inArray(yourVal, userLabels) !== -1) {
    doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this does give me the userLabels array. But when I use alert(userLabels[0]) to get 'Name', it does not work!

Comment: That's odd. It should work. What does `alert(userLabels)` get you?

Comment: The index keeps increasing for subsequent properties - 

var userLabels = dataset['person'][0]['userLabels'];
    var tagNames = dataset['person'][1]['tagNames'];
    var tableClass = dataset['person'][2]['tableClass'];
    var colWidths = dataset['person'][3]['colWidths'];

This works well throughout.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood what you were looking for. Check out @TheWeirdNerd's answer for a good suggestion on how to restructure your data in a cleaner way.